# How to align hover text beside input text field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I hover on input text field, the hover text should be displayed beside input text field, but in my code the hover text displayed below the input text field. can anyone give me a solution for this. below is my code.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: none;
}

input#userName:hover+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}

input#userName:focus+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-offset-2 form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6">User Name <span class="star">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="userName" id="userName" maxlength="100" />
      <span id="typePrompt">Allow only letters</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your HTML - `<form:input` ??

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Actually, I've used <form:form> tag to store the user data into database.

Comment: Indeed, there is a typo but it is not the cause of the issue described in the question (the text displaying below the text field instead of next to it).

Comment: OP, please edit your question to include that you're using `twitter-bootstrap` and add the Bootstrap CSS to your runnable snippet. You've got 2 close votes because folks don't realize that your example is actually incomplete and not showing the issue you're having. (I'd do it for you but there's a pending edit that needs review first and I already cast my vote on it.)

Comment: `<form:form>` is not valid either. Simply remove `form:` from that `input` tag and it works.. this is a typo surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `input` tag and `span` message text together with `display: flex;` and on hover then show. The `input` tag width set as `100%` on hover.
*Note: I used `white-space: nowrap;` for don't break the line of message text.*

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 84px;
}
.input-wrap{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.input-wrap:hover input#userName,
.input-wrap input#userName:focus{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
span#typePrompt {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.input-wrap:hover span#typePrompt,
.input-wrap input#userName:focus+span#typePrompt{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-offset-2 form-group">
            <label class="col-md-6">User Name <span class="star">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-wrap">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" path="userName" id="userName" maxlength="100" />
                    <span id="typePrompt">Allow only letters</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `form-control` class in bootstrap.
`form-control` class has `width: 100%`, and `display: block`, so the `span#typePrompt` cannot displayed inline,so it breaks to new line.
I solved it by using `d-flex` class and `w-50` class.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: none;
}

input#userName:hover+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}

input#userName:focus+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-offset-2 form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6">User Name <span class="star">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
      <input type="text" class="form-control w-50" path="userName" id="userName" maxlength="100" />
      <span id="typePrompt">Allow only letters</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can do it adding `d-inline-block w-50` class to your `input` tag.

Comment: d-inline-block w-50 class only works for me. but, the problem is text field is changed, I want only form control class text field.

Comment: Then you can add `display: inlin-block !important;` and `width: 50%` to `.form-control` class in your custom css file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the syntax form:input? Is this a form helper or something? Anyway, I changed that as @ProfessorAbronsius and SatoTakeru had already correctly noted. Then I wrapped the input and label field inside a form tag.

So your code was correct except for the form:input. So my answer is just for the sake of completeness and curiosity what actually form:input is?

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: none;
}

input#userName:hover+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}

input#userName:focus+span#typePrompt {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-offset-2 form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6">User Name <span class="star">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" path="userName" id="userName" maxlength="100" />
      <span id="typePrompt">Allow only letters</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you link bootstrap, you can find the problem.